# Count How Often One List Item is Found in Another List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have 3 sheets.

**Sheet 1** has a column, with the named range **PayCode,** of about 200 records, each containing a string. Each cell only contains one specific string, but each string can be found in multiple cells. A few of these strings represent if an employee is absent.

**Sheet 2** has a list of six unique strings of interest, with the named range **Absent**. These six strings are the possible Pay Codes that represent if an employee is absent, and they are what I am looking for in the **PayCode** column.

On **Sheet 3,** I would like to count how many times a string from **Absent** is found in **PayCode**.

Every suggestion I've found online has me doing a `COUNTIF` next to the list on **Sheet 2** to count how often each list item shows up, but I just want a count in one cell on **Sheet 3** of the total number of appearances of **Absent** list items in the **PayCode** column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF(Paycode,INDEX(Absent,1))+COUNTIF(Paycode,INDEX(Absent,2))+COUNTIF(Paycode,INDEX(Absent,3))+COUNTIF(Paycode,INDEX(Absent,4))+COUNTIF(Paycode,INDEX(Absent,5))+COUNTIF(Paycode,INDEX(Absent,6))
```

This method is ok since you are only dealing with 6 entries in your absent range. Basically you do a count if for each entry which is taken care of by the index then add the value for the next entry.  Hence the change of 1  to 2 to ...6 in the index.

## Update

Thanks to Scott Craner's comment, the above formula can be simplified as:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Paycode,absent))
```

Alternatively if you want a true array formula enter the following using CSE:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(paycode,absent))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `COUNTIF` may actually be the solution. You just need to set up Sheet 3 with the `COUNTIF` statements. These statements will reference to Sheet 2 to identify what you are looking for and then to Sheet 1 for the data that you will search through.

Your formula on sheet 3 would look something like this

`=countif(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A1)`

In this scenario `A:A` denotes the area that you're searching through and `A1` is the specific reference that you are looking for.

Option 2) 
If your search term may be confined within a longer string (ex, you are looking for "apple" but the string may be "an apple a day..." then you can use this formula:

`=countif(Sheet1!A:A,"*apple*")`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The issue with this is that I'd like to avoid having a `COUNTIF` for each item in my term list, even if it's on a separate sheet. I just want **ONE** formula that looks in my **Absent** term list, counts how many times those terms appear in the **PayCode** column, and returns the count.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like something you could do with the frequency function. You can find instructions here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/frequency-function-44e3be2b-eca0-42cd-a3f7-fd9ea898fdb9

Comment: According to that page, the `FREQUENCY` function ignores text. Is there another method that works for text and not just numbers?